# javascript element appear and then going away

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing "To Do App".
I have problem with adding card element.

HTML and Javascript file

```js
const addBtn=document.getElementById("addBtn");
const taskName=document.getElementById("txtTaskName");
const form=document.querySelector("form");
const eklencekYer=document.getElementById("eklenecekYer");




//New Task
const newTask=document.createElement("div")
newTask.className="card text-white bg-primary mb-3";
newTask.style="min-width: 18rem;";

const newTaskHeader=document.createElement("div");
newTaskHeader.className="card-header";
newTask.innerHTML="deneme"

const newTaskBody=document.createElement("div");
newTaskBody.className="card-body";

const newTaskBodyH=document.createElement("h5");
newTaskBodyH.className="card-title";
newTaskBodyH.innerText="deneme"

const newTaskBodyP=document.createElement("p");
newTaskBodyP.className="card-text";

newTaskBody.appendChild(newTaskBodyH);
newTaskBody.appendChild(newTaskBodyP);

newTask.appendChild(newTaskHeader);
newTask.appendChild(newTaskBody);




eventLisnteners();

function eventLisnteners(){
    form.addEventListener("submit",addBtninputValue);
};


function addBtninputValue(){
    eklencekYer.appendChild(newTask);

    if(!taskName.value==""){
        console.log("ee");
       


    }
    else{
        alert("İsim boş geçilemez");
    }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container p-5">
    <p>ToDo App</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="max-width: 56rem;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        New Task
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">

        <form id="addTaskForm">
          <div class="input-group mt-3">
            <input id="txtTaskName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a Name">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container" style="max-width: 56rem;">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="eklenecekYer" class="row">
        <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Danger card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Success card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="javascript.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

alright. when I press to add button.
card appear and then going away.

(also I want to know is there a better way for create element )

I guess in javascript file line 49 have same problems. `

(code was working btw, when i restart my computer its not working anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after submitting a form the page refresh automatically , you can prevent this behaivour by using preventDefault() method ,
change your addBtninputValue function like below :

```
function addBtninputValue(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    eklencekYer.appendChild(newTask);

    if(!taskName.value==""){
        console.log("ee");
       


    }
    else{
        alert("İsim boş geçilemez");
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much. my teacher told me preventDefault() for working only scrollbar and i didnt use. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add button has submit attribute. Browser would try to send data and the page would refresh. I have changed it to a *normal* button and modified the event handler accordingly.

I have moved your code which creates new card into a separate function, so that it returns a *new* div element each time your code runs. I have refactored it a little to add Title dynamically and you can further refactor it to include Header and Content dynamically.

```js
const addBtn=document.getElementById("addBtn");
const taskName=document.getElementById("txtTaskName");
const form=document.querySelector("form");
const eklencekYer=document.getElementById("eklenecekYer");


function createNewTask(task) {
  const newTask=document.createElement("div")
  newTask.className="card text-white bg-primary mb-3";
  newTask.style="min-width: 18rem;";

  const newTaskHeader=document.createElement("div");
  newTaskHeader.className="card-header";
  newTask.innerHTML="deneme"

  const newTaskBody=document.createElement("div");
  newTaskBody.className="card-body";

  const newTaskBodyH=document.createElement("h5");
  newTaskBodyH.className="card-title";
  newTaskBodyH.innerText=task

  const newTaskBodyP=document.createElement("p");
  newTaskBodyP.className="card-text";

  newTaskBody.appendChild(newTaskBodyH);
  newTaskBody.appendChild(newTaskBodyP);

  newTask.appendChild(newTaskHeader);
  newTask.appendChild(newTaskBody);

  return newTask;
}


eventLisnteners();

function eventLisnteners() {
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBtninputValue);    
};


function addBtninputValue() {
    eklencekYer.appendChild(createNewTask(taskName.value));
    if(!taskName.value==""){
        console.log("ee");
    } else {
        alert("İsim boş geçilemez");
    }
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container p-5">
    <p>ToDo App</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="max-width: 56rem;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        New Task
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">

        <form id="addTaskForm">
          <div class="input-group mt-3">
            <input id="txtTaskName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a Name">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="max-width: 56rem;">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="eklenecekYer" class="row">
        <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Danger card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card text-white bg-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-header">Header</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Success card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
              content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```